# Problems with COM object C#

Tags: com, c#-3.0

I have to adjust dll to be COM object (one main class in the class library). 
This dll has reference to other dlls.
When i'm using C# attributes for COM and register the dll, i can't work with this class, the registration register a lot of mess in the registry (few public classes in my class library, that i don't want to expose them as com).
It drive me crazy this issue, does anyone know whether com interface in C# force changes in the reference dlls (when i'm creating a simple class and interafce it works great, that why i think it is related to the references dlls)?
Please help me!!!

Thanks is advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

use Attibutes in that assembly. if you don't want public classes be visible as COM interfaces

```
[ComVisible(false)]
```

then there are some options how to make it COM-visible
one of them:
make an interface with attributes

```
 [ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
[Guid("new generated GUID")]
public interface ISample
{
 void DoSomthing();
}
```

then implement this interface

```
[Guid("new generated GUID")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(ISample))]
[ProgId("YourModule.YourClass")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class YourClass :  ISample
```

Comment: But the class i want to visible as com interface (and i set him as true), does not exist in the registry at all!!
Are you sure no changes needed for the referenced dlls?

Comment: Well, i have an interface (ISample) and static class factory (static class SampleFactory) that does not implemnt ISample interface, just has Create function which return ISample instance.
I want to expose those class as com visible. is it possible? actually, it is not work :(